# IIS7 manager password problems after Windows administrator password change

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, authentication, password, iis

Our network administrator recently left and, until we get another one, I'm filling in trying to keep the servers running :o

I changed the administrator password for the server (Windows Server 2008), and since then if I try to manage IIS through IIS Manager I get prompted for a username and password and I can't access it.  If I change the server administrator password back to the original then I can connect again.  Does anyone have any ideas please?

---

### Failed to connect

There was an error when trying to connect. Do you want to retype your credentials and try again?

Details:

### Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007052E)

### Yes   No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this, it was to do with shared configuration.  To fix this, I took the following steps:

1. Change the administrator password back to the old one
2. Open IIS manager
3. Change administrator password back to new password
4. Set the password in shared configuration

I believe it can also be fixed using appcmd, but I never worked out how.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following.

- Right click on the site and 'Basic Settings...'
- Click on 'Connect As...'
- Click on Specific User and give the new credentials.

Now it should work.